# Android Compatibility Library and New Software Releases

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-compatibility

**QUESTION**

I use a custom version of the `Compatibility Support Library` that enables me to use Google Maps with Fragments.

My question is, when new software releases happen, such as `Jelly Bean` just being released, will my compatibility library still work or will everything crash and break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it runs fine on your target version, it will run just fine on any greater version.

but its always a good thing to test it on real deive.

hope this answer your question.

Comment: Accepted for now, we'll see when it comes to full testing!